# CakePHP Multiple Controllers in page

Tags: cakephp

I am new to CakePHP and getting no help

I have 3 different controllers

```
1:: MenusController
2:: CategoriesController
3::ProductsController
```

on my home page in `header` I wand to show the Menu, in `sidebar` I would like to display all categories and on `content` area products belonging to default category.

How may I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [View Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements) making use of requestAction().

Your view will have 3 Elements calling every controller you mentioned.

This example is taken from the book:

The controller action

```
public function index() {
    $posts = $this->paginate();
    if ($this->request->is('requested')) {
        return $posts;
    } else {
        $this->set('posts', $posts);
    }
}
```

Then, in your view you will have something like

```
<h2>Latest Posts</h2>
<?php
    $posts = $this->requestAction(
        'posts/index/sort:created/direction:asc/limit:5'
    );
?>
<ol>
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <li><?php echo $post['Post']['title']; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you ver your response. Can you please explain it a bit more as I am new to Cake, really can't understand this example.

Comment: Do the blog tutorial first then and lookup the methods in the api documentation?

Comment: Yes, I am reading the documentation. But now I don't know if I should use ´requestAction´ in Element or should use ´loadModel´ in Controller. What will you suggest?

Comment: requestAction() because the logic stays in the domain where it should and you can re-use the element everywhere without relying on the controller setting the data for it.

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 3, this kind of scenario is handled by using View Cells.
See the documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html

View Cells allow the view to have controller-like logic to generate data to be rendered, without breaking the MVC model.

You could use a View Cell to generate a list of categories without having the performance hit of a requestAction call.

Answer (score -1):

I think the cleanest way to handle it is to create a component or helper and call it on your view.

- Building custom component can be found here:

  > http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#creating-a-component
- Building helper can be found here also :

> http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html